# Disk Partitioning for Ubuntu server with SQL server

Tags: server, mssql

I need help with 'Disk Partitioning'. I want to install an Ubuntu 16 LTS server without a graphical user interface as a virtual machine (ESX 6.5) with MS-SQL Express (3 databases, each max. 10 GB (MS-SQLe limit) + each 10 GB transaction log), and I don't know how to correct disk partition. My opinion is:

20–25 GB /
500 M /boot 
1 GB  /home 
65 GB /var/opt (MS-SQL is stored there) 
5 GB /var/log 
Swap 3 GB

I need to hear if I'm right.

Comment: There is no version 16 LTS do you mean 16.04 LTS?

Comment: The partition scheme that you've laid out will work, though it may be a little sparse and cause problems in the future. Do you *need* to have a minimal amount of disk space used? SQL Server's logs generally take up more space than the databases, and SQL Server Express does not have a log-size limit. Are the DBs seldom accessed? Or is maximum performance a goal as well? This would dictate how you partition across volumes ...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.4.7 LTS

Comment: 2Matigo: I'm limited by free space on VMware storage (200 GB free) and I want to change the trans. log size to the same size as DB, ie 10GB db + 10GB t.l.. So your opinion is 'more space' on /var/opt.

Comment: Opinion: Separate /boot is unnecessary on an unencrypted system. Separate /home is generally unnecessary on a limited-purpose server.

Comment: Unless paying for extra long term support you will have to update to newer version in April. Regular Ubuntu 16.04 is supported until April 2021. Better to use 20.04LTS or even 18.04LTS.

Comment: 2oldfred: thx, you are right, but I have to use 18.04LTS, because MS only supports MSSQL2017 / 2019 on ubuntu 16.4 LTS or 18.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Thx everyone,

Finally I will use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and partition the disk as follows :

25G / 
500M /boot (may be) 
5G /var/log  
65G /var/opt (but i try going to make it bigger) 
3G Swap

And I hope, that in the future i havent any problem with this partitioning.